# How to add class to <style></style>

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I would like to add css class inside a view and later call it.

Something like this:

```
<style>
  MarkSelectedRow {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
  }
</style>
```

I was trying to call that class:

```
  var MarkSelected = function (element) {

    var tdCaller = $(element);
    tdCaller.addClass("MarkSelectedRow");

  }
```

But, nothing happens. It seems like class is not defined. Is it possible to define class inside `<style></style>` and later use it in code?

Comment: you need a `.` before it: `.MarkSelectedRow {}`

Comment: This has got nothing to do with razor :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss the dot:

```
<style>
   .class_name {
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: you are right, thanks. Why downvoting on this? Explanation, please.

Comment: @FrenkyB I didn't downvote, otherwise I forgot to vote, but thumbs up

Comment: somebody downvoted on your post. My question was to him / her.

Comment: It was me but it had to be an upvote, edited just to undo that!